# Twitter bootstrap: looking to read some objective reviews

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

We are currently looking into [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/).

So far I've heard a lot of people speak with excitement about it. So we're reviewing this, and it's hard to find some founded opinions on why committing to something like bootstrap may also be a bad idea.

This is important for me to get a bit of a clear picture. A lot of frameworks have a bit of a trend to be really useful for rapid development early on, but then get in your way as your application advances.

So I'm not looking to hear why Bootstrap is good or bad, that would instantly close this question I'm sure, but I would love to know if there is some more reading material out there that will help be make an informed decision.

Comment: [Discussing the Pros and Cons of Using a CSS Framework](http://speckyboy.com/2011/03/14/discussing-the-pros-and-cons-of-using-a-css-framework/) - Good article on this subject.

Comment: Wish this wasn't "closed as off topic". It's a great question!